# Can you identify this Star Wars LEGO set?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Can anyone identify this Star Wars LEGO set:

[image]

Any help gratefully received. I think it's a Star Wars set.

Answer (score 4):

The top and right parts are from the [Ninjago Manta Ray Bomber](https://brickset.com/sets/70609-1/Manta-Ray-Bomber).

The parts on the left are from the [Star Wars Magazine Gift Y-Wing](https://brickset.com/sets/SW911730-1/Y-Wing).

The panel at the bottom left is from [Star Wars Death Star Final Duel](https://brickset.com/sets/75093-1/Death-Star-Final-Duel) (as per [Syberion](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/2481/syberion)).

Answer (score 2):

- The [Cylinder Quarter 4 x 4 x 6 with SW Death Star II Reactor Shaft Pattern (Stickers) - Set 75093](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30562pb036&in=S)
  comes from [75093 Death Star Final Duel](https://brickset.com/sets/75093-1/Death-Star-Final-Duel)